# Configuring Google Analytics Report Automation (Magic Script)

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use the Google Analytics Report Automation (Magic Script). I'm getting an error message after following the video made by Nick Mihailovski, with the instructions to configure Magic Script in Google Drive.

> Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.

I activated analytics in the project at Google API console, and then also I have activated in the spreadsheet the analytics button. The Drive interface's new design is different to the videos and doesn't let me enter the API code.

I thought it was automatic now but is not working for me. Can someone give me some advice?

I'm certain that I have followed all instructions. I have clicked "Make a core report" this works, but when I try to use Find Profiles Ids the error message shows up.

Comment: I think it's quite out of place your comment... really not helpful at all and degrades this space... please delete.

Comment: Ok - deleted.  Sorry and good luck getting what you need solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had/having the same issue.  There are revised instructions, in writing below that video you may want to try.  Although, now I am getting a different error, but I thought this might help you and you'll have better luck than I.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/report-automation-magic

Answer (score 0):

The Google team have been busy. Check this out:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

I believe this has replaced Nick's amazing script. The only problem is I have not found triggers, so will need to dig into this.

Jan

Comment: Hi Jan , it's strange but all the instructions are imposible to perform in my browser, none of the mentioned menus exist... "google spreadsheet" maybe in some regions of the world  has been released but in my location google drive doesn't have the mentioned links in the menu... or maybe i don't see it... please if it is there let me know where!! i Need it. In my google drive there is no Google "Add-ons" but scripts... etc... when i search Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on nothing comes up.

Comment: I have been searching more BUT Cant find the feature... checked here too https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/search?query=Google+Analytics+Spreadsheet+